# Importing specified tables dynamically from one database to another using SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, dynamic, ssis

I need to create an SSIS package that dynamically creates the source tables in the destination database and loads daily ongoing deltas into the destination tables from the source database. However, the only way I imagine this being possible is with a script component and I am not particularly fluent with C#.

Can someone help point me down the right path?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Have you tried to use replication?

Comment: I have considered it, but replication is not an option in this case.

Comment: Does SSIS still support VB scripting?

Comment: Yes, via a script component. It would need to be C# though.

Comment: Dynamic how? If logical, it can be done in a multiple number of ways.

Answer (score 0):

Consider X ->source database     ,        Y -> Destination database

a1,a2,a3 are three variables used in package

1.Then in executesql task get the databases what u want frm particular database.
assign it to object variable(let a1).

2.then add foreachloop container add that variable(a1) as **ado.net variable** in foreachloop container and assign a3 as resultset variable.

3.In container add executesql task in that add query with variable(a2)

in variable a2 with string add query as

```
"INSERT INTO b.dbo."+@[User::a3]+"( *fieldlist* )
SELECT * FROM a.dbo."+@[User::a3]
```

4.then run ur package what ever present in your source database will come into destination